# How to delete an attachment on the wiki?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It could be that I'm missing something, but does anyone know how to delete an attachment from a wiki page? Clicking the *del* link on the *attachment* page of the wiki page takes me back to the wiki page itself with an error admonition at the top stating:

> Please use the interactive user interface to use action AttachFile.del!
>
> Clear message

I've found some posts to the *moin-user* list mentioning this same error message [[1](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.wiki.moin.general/8202)], but no solution / work-around I can use.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140301/how-to-delete-an-attachment-on-the-wiki?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2014-03-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like a bug in the wiki at the moment. TIcketed here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/108

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-04-27**:
Ok, thanks for the response. I'll post back to this answer when / if this gets resolved.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-05-21**:
This seems to have been solved. Marking as accepted. Thanks.